# Search DataGridView for Integer Then Select Row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

The below code should search `DataGridView1` which is on the `LeaderAccessTable` form for an integer that the user inputs into `SendFromID`, if the `DataGridView1`'s first column contains what the integer that the user has entered into `SendFromID` then the entire row should be selected. However it doesn't select any rows at all... Can anyone see why? This code is ran from a separate form.

```
Dim intcount As Integer
For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Rows
  If LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Rows(intcount).Cells(0).Value.ToString = SendFromID.Text Then
    LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Rows(intcount).Selected = True
  End If
Next
MsgBox("Done.")
```

Comment: It's likely a problem that your not referring to the instance of the form which has the data not the {formname}.{controlname} reference  - which is legal to call, but gets you no where.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this code worked.

```
Dim v_SelectRow As Integer
        For counter = 0 To (LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
            For counter2 = 0 To (LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                If (LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains(SendFromID.Text)) Then
                    LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells(0).Selected = True
                    v_SelectRow = LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
                    CurrentPoints.Text = LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.Item(8, v_SelectRow).Value
                    'Do Something
                    Else
                    'Do Something
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```